# Store file outputs of command in bash variables

Tags: bash, pipe

Suppose I have a utility `foo` that writes to `n` different files simultaneously. Different data is written to every file. What is written to the files is not known in advance. For example, the utility might be invoked like:

```bash
foo file_1 file_2 ... file_n
```

I want to store what is written to the files in bash variables. Of course, I could let the utility write to actual files on the file system and then read from them:

```bash
foo file_1 ... file_n

output_1="$(cat file_1)"
...
output_n="$(cat file_n)"

rm file_1 ... file_n
```

However, I think it might be more efficient to skip the file system and avoid creating temporary files. How can this be done? Can named pipes maybe be used for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found an answer. The problem with @terdon's solution is, as @ilkkachu mentioned, that it assumes the files to be written in sequential order. It first reads from `file1` until completion, and then continues to `file2`. However, `foo` might write to `file1` and `file2` at the same time, and because no reader is attached to `file2`, it blocks.

This could be fixed by opening every fifo for reading right after invoking `foo`, and then reading from them in sequential order. However, this only works as long as `foo` does not write more than the fifo buffer size.

Every file/fifo thus needs to be read concurrently. For each fifo we can create a subshell that runs in the background and reads from the fifo until completion. The subshell then prints the content to stdout. It thereby serves as a buffer for the data that is written to the fifo.

```bash
# assume files don't exist yet
mkfifo "$@"

# opens fifos as writing
foo "$@" &

# for each fifo, create background subshell that reads from it
i=0
for file in "$@"; do
    exec {fd}< <(echo "$(cat $file)")
    fds[$i]=$fd
    (( i++ ))
done

# fifos are now fully connected
# consume content buffered in subshells
i=0
for file in "$@"; do
    file_contents[i]="$(cat <&${fds[$i]})"
    (( i++ ))
done

for (( i=0; i<${#file_contents[@]}; i++)); do
  printf "The contents of file number %d are: %s\n" "$(( $i+1 ))" "${file_contents[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly what named pipes (also known as FIFOs) are for. Here's a toy example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for file in "$@"; do
  mkfifo "$file"
  printf "This is file '%s'\n" "$file" > "$file" &
  file_contents[i]=$(cat < "$file")
  rm "$file"
  (( ++i ))
done

for (( i=0; i<${#file_contents[@]}; i++)); do
  printf "The contents of file number %d are: %s\n" "$i" "${file_contents[i]}"
done
```

This looks like you're creating and deleting files, and formally you are; but they're named pipes and not *regular* files and therefore no data are actually written to disk.

However, this still uses the filesystem, strictly speaking, it just uses it minimally. The file has no contents, so nothing is actually written to disk, but there will be a filesystem entry created for it. From `man fifo`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       A  FIFO  special file (a named pipe) is similar to a pipe, except that
       it is accessed as part of the filesystem.  It can be opened by  multi‐
       ple  processes  for reading or writing.  When processes are exchanging
       data via the FIFO, the kernel passes all data internally without writ‐
       ing it to the filesystem.  Thus, the FIFO special file has no contents
       on the filesystem; the filesystem entry merely serves as  a  reference
       point  so  that  processes  can  access  the  pipe using a name in the
       filesystem.
```

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$@"; do
  ## CAREFUL: this will delete any files with the same name if they exist
  if [ -e "$file" ]; then
    rm -- "$file"
  fi
  mkfifo -- "$file"
done

## This is your utility
foo "$@" &

## And now read the variables
i=0
for file in "$@"; do
  file_contents[i]=$(cat < "$file")
  rm -- "$file"
  (( ++i ))
done

## And here you can use the file_contents array to do whatever you need
for (( i=0; i<${#file_contents[@]}; i++)); do
  printf "The contents of file number %d are: %s\n" "$i" "${file_contents[i]}"
done
```

To run `foo file1 file2 file3` you would just run that script with `file1 file2 file3` as its arguments:

```
my_script.sh file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: Thanks! But where is the utility called? I do not want to *create* the utility `foo` from my question, but rather take it as given and change its output behavior.

Comment: @LeCapoChino see updated answer. Is that better?

Comment: Yes, thank you! But I don't think this would run. You are creating FIFOs and and then tell `foo` to write to them, before attaching a process to the reading end. The fifo man page states: *"The FIFO
       must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data can
       be passed.  Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end
       is opened also."* (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html). Your script would thus block forever.

Comment: @LeCapoChino yes, that's why the toy example sent the `printf` to the background. I forgot to add `&` to the line calling `foo`. I have now done so. I _think_ that it will work this way, I know I've done similar things with tools designed to handle biological data, but I am not an expert (or anything remotely like one) on this sort of thing so I could well be wrong. Could you give it a try and let me know?

Comment: One worry is whether you might need to read from all files at once. I don't know.

Comment: The pipes should at least be open for reading from the start, so `foo` can write to any of them. E.g. if the reader reads just from the first pipe to begin with, but `foo` starts writing from the second, it'd block there. Or if the writer tries to open them all first, before writing to any of them, as it looks like the open already blocks if there's no reader.

Comment: There might be some way to open the read sides of all pipes first from the script (e.g. `exec 9<pipe1` and then `cat <&9` etc.), but even that might end up blocking if the writer writes enough to fill the pipe buffers before closing any of them. So, yeah, in the worst case, you'd need to read from all of them at the same time, and I don't think that's easy in the shell. (except zsh has some module to support select(), but I'm not sure how easy that'd be)

Comment: of course if the program is nice, and opens and writes the output files in order from left to right, then it should be straightforward. I'd just use the temp files, operating systems have caches for this sort of thing anyway, and if in doubt, the temp files could be put on `tmpfs` or some other in-memory filesystem

Comment: Thanks, @ilkkachu. I was thinking of something like wanting to avoid I/O over the network with NFS or other such network file systems. That's where I mostly use fifos myself and tmp files wouldn't help there (sure you could find a local filesystem but there's often not enough space when working with large volumes of data).

Comment: @terdon, yeah. Though if the volumes are so large that a temp file becomes an issue, I wonder if reading the data in to a shell variable will work that well either... Streaming through a pipe or named pipe would be different, of course.